# Using TextBox as Path Like OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net

I hope someone can help me.
In short, I have this little code
I can't replace "*Path from my pc*" with a *string/textbox* in any way

The intention would be this:

```
enumerator = SpotifyBox.Text.Split.GetEnumerator
```

It doesn't give me errors, but it doesn't work as it should once the button starts

```
Dim enumerator As List(Of String).Enumerator = New List(Of String).Enumerator()
    Dim class70 As Action(Of String())


    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(40, 40)
    Dim strArrays As List(Of String()) = New List(Of String())()
    Try
        Try

            enumerator = File.ReadLines(Path from pc).ToList().GetEnumerator()
            While enumerator.MoveNext()
                Dim current As String = enumerator.Current
                If (If(Not current.Contains(":"), True, String.IsNullOrEmpty(current))) Then
                    Continue While
                End If
                strArrays.Add(current.Split(New Char() {":"c}))
            End While
        Finally
            DirectCast(enumerator, IDisposable).Dispose()
        End Try
        int_5 = strArrays.Count
    Catch exception1 As System.Exception


    End Try
```

Comment: _It doesn't give me errors_ - remove redundant `Try .. Catch`. There are no benefit of using enumerator, because all lines already loaded into a memory by `.ToList()`

Comment: Are you seriously asking us how to get a `String` from a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is some crazy code and the question you're asking is not the question you need an answer to.  Based on what you have posted, it seems that you have a file path in a `TextBox` named `SpotifyBox` and you want to read the lines from that file with some processing.  In that case, get rid of all that craziness and do this:

```
Dim filePath = SpotifyBox.Text
Dim records As New List(Of String())

For Each line In File.ReadLines(filePath)
    If line.Contains(":") Then
        records.Add(line.Split(":"c))
    End If
Next
```

That's it, that's all.  You pretty much never need to create an enumerator directly.  Just use a `For Each` loop.

Comment: thanks for help but give me error:

System.ArgumentException: 'invalid characters in the path.'

Comment: Then enter a valid path into the `TextBox`. That's an example of WHY you should be using an `OpenFileDialog`. It will ensure that the path is valid. There's nothing to stop you using the dialogue to get the path to populate the `TextBox`.

Comment: We can't help you with that error because we can't see what you have typed into SpotifyBox.